# Necessity of absolute value in The Fubini–Tonelli theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

In The Fubini–Tonelli theorem([reference in wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#The_Fubini.E2.80.93Tonelli_theorem)):

What's the point of taking absolute value in $\int_{X\times Y}|f(x,y)|\,d(x,y)$? Isn't $f$ integrible in $X\times Y$ automatically implies $|f|$ integrable in $X\times Y$? So we only need $f$ integrable to apply  Fubini–Tonelli theorem?

Answer (score 1):

To say that $f$ is integrable means (in this context) that the integral of $|f|$ is finite. The following statements both say the same thing:

- $f$ is integrable.
- The integral of $|f|$ is finite.

There are cases in which the two iterated integrals not equal to each other, but that can happen only when the integral of $f$ over that part of the domain in which $f\ge0$ is $+\infty$ and over that part of the domain in which $f\le 0$ is $-\infty.$ An example is
$$
\int_0^1 \left( \int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \, dy \right) \, dx \ne \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \, dx \right) \, dy.
$$
(One of these is $+\pi/2$ and the other is $-\pi/2.$) Thus Fubini's theorem tells us that
$$
\iint_{[0,1]^2} \left| \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \right| \,d(x,y) = +\infty.
$$
Tonelli's theorem is applicable even when the integral is infinite. It assumes $f\ge0$ everywhere.

Comment: Isn't $\int f d(x,y) < \infty \Leftrightarrow \int |f| d(x,y) < \infty$? Because $\int f$ by definition $= \int f^+ -\int f^{-}$

Comment: If $f$ is measurable then $\displaystyle \int |f|\, d(x,y)$ is defined and has a value in $[0,+\infty].$ But $\displaystyle \int f\, d(x,y)$ is in some cases undefined, as in the example above.

Comment: But if $\int f$ is undefined, $\int |f|$ will be $\infty$, it still doesn't seem matter that we just get rid of the absolute value in the statement of Fubini–Tonelli theorem.

Comment: @CYC : How do you say what it means to call the integral "undefined" without saying the integrals of $f^+$ and of $f^-$ are both finite?

Answer (score 0):

No .The theorem holds for all non-negative measurable functions; you compute the repeated iterated integral of the absolute value of of f and if it comes out finite you CONCLUDE the $f$ is integrable so you may then apply Fubini to $f$ to calculate the integral of $f$ by iterated integrals -very useful result

Comment: Isn't $\int f d(x,y) < \infty \Leftrightarrow \int |f| d(x,y) < \infty$?

Comment: Yes but  you don't know f is integrable or that |f| is integrable when you start in an application . You can use the Tonelli extnsion without knowing that f is integrable ;